# I've uploaded an image for my website on s3 but it doesn't display on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I've uploaded an image for my website on s3 but it doesn't display on my website. It works fine on my localhost, as the picture is in my assests/images folder of my Rails 5 app, but not on Heroku. When I inspect my page, I do see an error for the file my code is looking for: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .I do believe I have my Heroku set up right with my amazon s3 bucket because I can see users' pictures being sent to it. I'm looking to use this picture as a background for part of my landing page. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You really haven't provided any specifics. For example: What's the URI to the image? And what's the URI your app is looking for? Without more details, it's anyone's guess. (please edit your question; don't put details in comments).

Comment: Thank you. You asking those questions helped me realize what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I made the image inside my 's3 bucket' public so that it could be accessed by my website. Also, I changed my url for the image in my Rails app to the new url provided by amazon s3.